# PRISM module app.config configuration settings

Tags: c#, wpf, configuration, module, prism

We have the beginnings of a modular wpf application built using prism.

We want to allow for each module to have specific configuration - app settings / connection strings etc.

We've currently got things working by specifying all configuration in the shell project as a short term fix. Clearly this breaks the modular approach we are looking for - can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to rename `app.config` for every specific module to something like `YourModule.Name.config` and load that file in your module with code like:

```
var filename = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
var configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(filename);
if (configuration != null)
    _setting = configuration.AppSettings.Settings["SettingName"].Value;
```

Maybe you should play some with filename (like adding .config in the end), I can't check it right now.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but thanks very much, this works. Just surprised that there is not more mentioned on this in the prism documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Have an interface IConfigurationManager in your infrastructure project. Create a ConfigurationManger project which can handle sections of settings corresponding to modules in a configuration file.Register this configuration manager with IConfigurationManager in your application. With each module you inject the configurationmanager instance and read/write config values.

```
class MyModule(IConfigurationManager config, ....)
{
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a blog post solving similar issue you are trying to solve.
hope it helps.

http://www.thedailyomelette.com/2013/02/maintain-multiple-configs.html

Comment: It's always better to post your answer here, than to give links to blogs that'll die someday.

Comment: Guess what - the link is dead now. I would have loved to read the answer.